# It looks like the spacing for the last modified tagline lost its right justification

Tags: bug, whitespace

This feels wrong in my brain, so I think it's a new change... If the tag list is short, the line showing last modification and the user+rep loses its right-justification (red), but if the tag list is long enough to cause a linewrap, it is properly right-justified (green).

[image]

This happens here on MSE as well as the main page of Physics.SE and Physics Meta. I suspect it is global, but I haven't looked at any other sites. This is Firefox 89.0 (64 bit) on Windows 10, and I haven't tried other browsers or OSes.